# problem with reference voltage of AD620

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

This is a AD620 instrumentation amplifier for single supply operation
when i tested the below circuit on a bread board , it is giving zero voltage output   for input of  0V to 1V input and then giving offset voltage . For example if i give 3 volts it is giving 2 volts at pin 6.. But when i connect it in dual supply mode its working fine, please some one help me. when i simulated the circuit on multisim it is working fine for both the modes

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're applying inputs that are well outside the common-mode input range of the chip. See the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD620.pdf).

[image]

You should not use this graph either, but use the guaranteed range, which means you should not expect proper operation with less than about 2V applied to the inputs (relative to -Vs) or closer to +Vs than about 1.5V.

[image]

Comment: For OP's benefit, the usual solution is to use both positive and negative supplies with the '620.

Comment: Yup.  The AD623 is the right part for this job (and its pin compatible)

Comment: if i have to  give input of 30 mv to 500 mv , will AD 623 be a better option

Comment: The **Absolute Maximum** supply voltage of the AD623 is only **12V** so I think it might be rather unreliable at 12V nominal supply. It might also have trouble providing an output > 1V with ~0V CM voltage, check the data sheet carefully (eg. [Fig 23](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD623.pdf)).